# How to retrieve value from dynamically created textbox by javascript using Vb

Tags: javascript, vb.net, dynamic

I am using javascript code to add dynamic text box and it is work. 
But there are problem when I wish to get the value that enter in the dynamic created textbox in Vb.

I tried to put runat="server" in the DIV that I use to add textbox, but the add function cannot work after I put runat="server" in the DIV.

Anyone know how to retrieve value from the textbox that are dynamically added by javascript by using Vb?

Below is my javascript code use to add textbox.

```
var x = InputsWrapper.length; 
var FieldCount = 1;

$(AddButton).click(function(e)  //on add input button click
{
    if (x < MaxInputs) {
        FieldCount++;
        var setID = ("field_1" + FieldCount); 
        $(InputsWrapper).append('<div><input  id="' + setID + '"  type="text" placeholder="Item title..."/><a href="#" "" class="removeclass">&times;</a></div>');
        x++; 
    }


return false;
});
<
```

Comment: Give the input field a name, put the DIV inside a form and submit it

Comment: Yes, I had put it in the form already and it is success. But I have no idea on how to retrieve the input value from the textbox I dynamically added by using Vb.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21622503/how-to-get-the-text-value-of-dynamically-created-textbox

Comment: Hi @mplungjan , thanks for the suggestion. I solved this problem by put name in div as your suggestion and use the name to retrieve the value in Vb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modify the textbox by adding name="txtDy" and using Request.Form in Vb.net to retrieve the value.
Vb will automatic save the value of all "txtDy" textbox and split it by default symbol, something like ("123,abc,456,def").
So I split the string and using for loop to get the value of each textbox.

```
Dim txtDyList As String = Request.Form("txtDy")
Dim txtDynamic() As String = txtDyList.Split(",")

For i As Integer = 0 To txtDynamic.Length - 1
   MsgBox(txtDynamic(i)) 'I can get the value from here: txtDynamic(i)
Next
```